# How to select multiple id's with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I want to select all skill_id where job_id equals = 1 , is there a way around this using a simple sql query ?

in this example : i want sql to return 1 and 2 as skill_id
thanks

Comment: `select skill_id from table where job_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple SQL query, and it can be done as follows:

```
SELECT skill_id 
FROM table_name 
WHERE job_id = 1;
```

You will get your 2 values as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT DISTINCT skill_id
FROM table_name 
WHERE job_id = 1;
```